# 8 dice and probability of distinct values

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

NOT HW just practrice question

If eight distinct dice are rolled what is the probability that all six numbers appear ?

The chapter is INclusion and exclusion and the answer in the back of the text is :

$\frac{6^8}{6^8}-\binom{6}{1}\frac{5^8}{6^8}+\binom{6}{2}\frac{4^8}{6^8}-\binom{6}{3}\frac{3^8}{6^8}+\binom{6}{2}\frac{2^8}{6^8}-\binom{6}{1}\frac{1^8}{6^8}$

I am trying to understand this answer.. and what I follow is that the first term $\frac{6^8}{6^8}$ is the probability of the first number and then we subtract probability of the second number appearing $\binom{6}{1}\frac{5^8}{6^8}$ but why is it multiplied by $\binom{6}{1}$ or perhaps I am not interpreting the answer correctly. Could use some intuition n understanding this answer.

Comment: In high school, $\binom{n}{k}$ is sometimes called $C_k^n$, or $C_n^k$, or $C(n,k)$, or ${}_nC_k$, and I have not mentioned all the variants!

Comment: is your question about what $\binom{n}{k}$ means, or about why the book uses the expression this particular way?

Comment: sorry what I meant is in this question what does it represents. SOrry I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 1):

It's a binomial coefficient, given by
$$
\binom{a}{b}=\dfrac{a!}{b!(a-b)!}
$$

for $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, $a\geq b$. Find more in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: sorry what I meant is in this question what does it represents. SOrry I should have been more clear.

Comment: Whoops... try asking another question :)